# addClass in $(window).resize function .on('click' not working

Tags: jquery

Please have a look at the [jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/3aRqA/](http://jsfiddle.net/3aRqA/)

If the background is orange means the ul has `mobile-nav`added as class name else the background will be yellow.

Now if it is orange and we click on a link it should alert here, but nothing will happen.

If I uncomment the line in `$(document).ready(function....`it will work, also if I add the class in the markup section.

What am I doing wrong? I want the class `mobile-nav`to toggle depending on screen size and of course the on.('click' to be working if I have the class `ul.nav.mobile-nav...`

here is the code, thanks for help!

```
<span class="show-window-width"></span>

<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Four</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d = {};
d.winW = $(window).width();


$( window ).resize(function() {
    d.winW = $(window).width();
    $('.show-window-width').html(d.winW);
    isMobileNav();
});

function isMobileNav() {
    if(d.winW<=400) {
        $('ul.nav').addClass('mobile-nav');
    } else {
        $('ul.nav').removeClass('mobile-nav');
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    //$('ul.nav').addClass("mobile-nav");

    $('ul.nav.mobile-nav > li > a').on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("here");
    });
});
</script>


<style>
ul.nav {
    background-color:yellow;
}
ul.nav.mobile-nav {
    background-color:orange;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use event-delegation since the elements class is dynamic.

```
$(document).on('click','ul.nav.mobile-nav > li > a',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("here");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3aRqA/1/)

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, but I stopped because `preventDefault()` will not work as expected with event delegation (it is too late to prevent the default behavior since the event has already bubbled up to the document). This might prevent the questioner from using your code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah, but then we could use another delegation directly on the element using `preventDefault()` or?

Comment: We can, but the questioner may want the default behavior to be prevented only if the `mobile-nav` class is applied. In that case, we would be back to square one.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah i see :S, i had no idea about preventDefault() not working as it should with event delegation.

Comment: I would like to say I know what you guys are talking about, fact is, I've got no idea :( I use e.preventDefault() so that a href is not working (it will just toggle a subnav). is that the wrong way to do it? it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Event binding are bind once the document is ready and not "live".

You could bind the click on the `a` no matter what the window size is, but inside the event handler, you check the class :

```
$('ul.nav > li > a').on('click',function(e) {
        if($(this).closest('.mobile-nav').length){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("here");
        }
});
```